# Hadoop library conflict at mapreduce time

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I have a jar that uses the Hadoop API to launch various remote mapreduce jobs (ie, im not using the command-line to initiate the job). The service jar that executes the various jobs is built with maven's "jar-with-dependencies".

My jobs all run fine except one that uses commons-codec 1.7, I get:

> FATAL org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child: Error running child : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeAsString([B)Ljava/lang/String;

I think this is because my jar is including commons-codec 1.7 whereas my Hadoop install's lib has commons-codec 1.4 ...

Is their any way to instruct Hadoop to use the distributed commons-codec 1.7 (I assume this is distributed as a job dependency) rather than the commons-codec 1.4 in the hadoop 1.0.3 core lib?

Many thanks!

**Note:** Removing commons-codec-1.4.jar from my Hadoop library folder does solve the problem, but doesn't seem too sane. Hopefully there is a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:

- You should be able to exclude commons-codec from within the hadoop dependency and add another explicit dependency for commons-codec
- Try setting the scope to provided so that none of the hadoop jars get included.  This assumes that those jars would be in the runtime class path.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, not 100% sure what you mean about the first point and the second point, my hadoop client libraries in the pom are already set to provided scope.

Comment: Within the dependency block in a pom you can list a number of implied dependencies that should be excluded from the maven action.  So if version 1.4 is the indirectly implied version you can exclude that and explicitly include a new dependency for 1.7 in your pom.

Comment: Yep, that is already being done. commons-codec 1.7 is added to the pom with hadoop libs being provided. The problem is when hadoop enters the MR after distributing my jar to the job tracker.