# Exception while connection to cassandra in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, cassandra

I am trying to connect to cassandra in my java code. When I run the application I get following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets.newConcurrentHashSet()Ljava/util/Set;
```

I am using
    Cassandra 2.1.2
    Hadoop 2.6.0

```
Any help is highly appreciated.
```

Comment: It looks like you have a conflict in versions of guava used by cassandra and hadoop.

Comment: Same as this one [NoSuchMethodError Sets.newConcurrentHashSet() while running jar using hadoop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27089126/432903) but unanswered.