# NoSuchMethodError when running on Hadoop but not when run locally

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

While running program on Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.3.1 MapReduce gives me below error :

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.withFallback
```

But when I test by executing JAR :

```
java -cp myclass
```

It runs flawlessly. I am out of idea here as if so called **Futures.withFallback** is present in JAR thats why its got executed in local. Its using Guava for connecting Cassandra, full stack trace is below:

```
attempt_201507081740_21115_m_000050_0: [FATAL] Child - Error running child : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.withFallback(Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/FutureFallback;Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;)Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;
attempt_201507081740_21115_m_000050_0:  at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.initAsync(Connection.java:176)
attempt_201507081740_21115_m_000050_0:  at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:721)
attempt_201507081740_21115_m_000050_0:  at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.tryConnect(ControlConnection.java:244)
attempt_201507081740_21115_m_000050_0:  at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:190)
attempt_201507081740_21115_m_000050_0:  at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:78)
attempt_201507081740_21115_m_000050_0:  at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1272)
attempt_201507081740_21115_m_000050_0:  at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:158)
attempt_201507081740_21115_m_000050_0:  at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:248)
attempt_201507081740_21115_m_000050_0:  at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:281)
attempt_201507081740_21115_m_000050_0:  at com.cassandra.CassandraHandler.getConnection(CassandraHandler.java:40)
attempt_201507081740_21115_m_000050_0:  at com.json.flatten.DynamicJsonFlattener.<init>(DynamicJsonFlattener.java:35)
attempt_201507081740_21115_m_000050_0:  at com.mapreduce.Map.map(Map.java:18)
attempt_201507081740_21115_m_000050_0:  at com.mapreduce.Map.map(Map.java:13)
attempt_201507081740_21115_m_000050_0:  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:140)
attempt_201507081740_21115_m_000050_0:  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:672)
attempt_201507081740_21115_m_000050_0:  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
attempt_201507081740_21115_m_000050_0:  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
attempt_201507081740_21115_m_000050_0:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
attempt_201507081740_21115_m_000050_0:  at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
 attempt_201507081740_21115_m_000050_0:  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
attempt_201507081740_21115_m_000050_0:  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
```

Is something wrong with Hadoop version or any other version clash.
Any ideas please!

EDIT: I have verified that there is no "withFallback" method present in Guava v18 JAR. Now I am clueless, please help me with any ideas !

Comment: `withFallback` was added to version 14 of Guava. It looks like when running with `java`, you have Guava >= 14 on your classpath, but lower than that when running in Hadoop. I am looking for information about Hadoop but I have never used neither it nor Guava...

Comment: Are you using a google dependency?

Comment: @Chop I have v18 for Guava

Comment: @JohnSnow yes I am using Guava's dependency !

Answer (score 1):

Edited:  didn't saw your stacktrace. your stacktrace show that there is a version miss match. you can find appropriate compatible version on there documentations.

make sure that required jar files are available in your classpath.

when you are running using -cp option, your jvm searches for required jar file in all directory locations separated by ; given in your classpath variable.

make sure you have also added ;.; in your classes path, which causes the jvm to load/search class/jar files available in your current working directory as well.

Comment: All the JAR files including Guava v18 Jar is available in Class path, Its running using JAVA but its not running in Hadoop , why?

Comment: where you see version mismatch in stacktrace?

Comment: Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/FutureFallback;Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;)Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;

you have this method and jar in your classpath but. your application is unable to find what it really needs to do the job..

Comment: I have also specified . (dot) as class path while building the JAR, but why Hadoop can't find the method and java finds it ? Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found the problem (or at least a resolution for me).

If you happen to be using Google's `google-api-client` library:

[`com.google.api-client » google-api-client`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client/1.20.0)

it has a dependency on [`guava-jdk5 13.0`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava-jdk5/13.0). This version of `guava-jdk5` does not have **`Futures.withFallback`** (that was introduced in `14.0`) and could likely be conflicting with your dependency on guava.

The solution, if this is your case, is to add a dependency to `com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0`. It's a `JDK5` backport of `guava`, but it does work to resolve this issue.

Why Google has this dependency on a *very* old guava version (and a backport nonetheless) is beyond me.

Comment: Its not the google-api-client but its Hadoop which still uses v11, I don't know why?