# NoSuchMethodError when not calling the method directly, but a service method

Tags: java

When I am calling corresponding method, I see the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/google/common/collect/Sets.newIdentityHashSet()Ljava/util/Set;
```

This is my code:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget sendWT = client.target(blueMailUrl);
url.openConnection();           
Invocation.Builder builder = ((WebTarget) sendWT)                  
     .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     .header("Authorization","Basic " + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary((byte[]) (blueMailUserid + ":" + blueMailPassword)
     .getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

Comment: This may be helpful: https://reflectoring.io/nosuchmethod/

Comment: The method is there in Guava 19.0 (Refer: https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html). I would suggest looking at the jar files you have on classpath, this type of error often occurs due to earlier versions of jar files being on classpath with the required version and the earlier version shadows the required jar. Check once.

Comment: yes ,i checked in my class path jar is there.and this has only one version .I am using "google-collect-0.5.jar".It has only one version .

Comment: Even I am trying with the jar "jersey-guava-2.23.1" ,for this also same error .Anyone have experienced on this .Please suggest me how to resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` occurs when a method (actually the class) is available during compilation and the same is missing during runtime.

Make sure all the dependencies of the project is added to the classpath during runtime

In your case, check google-collections jar file is available in the classpath

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError occurs when a method (actually the class) is available during compilation and the same is missing during runtime. :::  How we can avoid this one ,please tell us.Thank you

Comment: @HemalataMohanta It has been answered here, look at the solution provided here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249002/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-google-common-collect-sets-newconcurrenthashset